# Find class files in jar which is inside a tar.gz file

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a tar.gz or a tgz file with multiple jar and other files. I need to scan and delete some class files inside these jar files.

I have got them in parts however not all together; e.g.
To list all jar files in the archive,

```
tar tf MyTar.tar.gz --wildcards "*.jar"
SomeJar-2.6.2.jar
SomeJar-2.8.2.jar
```

And to delete the class file using the command; ( after extracting the tar file)

```
zip -q -d `find . -name "*.jar" -exec grep -Hsli "Abcd.class" {} \;` \*/Abcd.class
```

I tried using exec however I am unable to make it work

```
tar tf MyTar.tar.gz --wildcards "*.jar" -exec ls {};
tar: invalid option -- 'e'
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

Any suggestions to make exec work or some other way to scan and delete class files from a jar in a tar.gz file

Comment: Try `tar ... |  xargs ...`

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message tells you, `-exec` is not a valid option to the `tar` command. I guess you are mixing it with `find`, which does provide such an option (or rather, in that specific context, predicate).

In the general case, to pass the output of a command as an argument to another command, try `xargs`.

```
tar tf MyTar.tar.gz --wildcards "*.jar" |
xargs ls
```

If I understand your question at all, you need something different here, though. (Also, [don't use `ls` in scripts.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)) Something like this maybe?

```
for jar in *.jar; do
    zip -q -d "$jar" \*/Abcd.class
done
```

If you wanted to check whether the `jar` file contains a member with that name, you could add a filter to `continue` the loop if it's not there before you run the `zip -d`, but running it on all files is simple, obvious, and harmless (though you might get an error message for files with no matches).

After processing the `jar` files, you'd `tar` them back together if that's the format you want them in.